# Edittext background not working properly in some devices

Tags: android, background, android-edittext

Hi I am facing one small issue.I have tried to set background to my edittext from drawable.It works fine in most of the devices but not working in some devices.The background of the edittext will turned to dark black in some devices.I don't know why it is happening??

Here is my drawable edittext,

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<stroke
    android:width="0.3dp"
    android:color="#1c1b20" >
</stroke>

<padding
    android:bottom="4dp"
    android:left="4dp"
    android:right="4dp"
    android:top="4dp" >
</padding>

<!-- Here is the corner radius -->
<corners android:radius="5dp" >
</corners>
```

And I am applying it to my edittext as,

```
    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/e3"
    style="@style/custom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890_@-."
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/usernamem"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:hint="@string/username"
    android:padding="5dip" />
```

The whole edittext is turned to black.Even I removed applying theme to edittext it seems same.I thought it is because of api level of the device.Is it co

Can anyone figured me out why I am facing this??

Comment: can you show screenshots? also, is there any similary among the devices that have the problem? maybe the screen size, android version, etc? these info would help a lot in helping you debug this.

Comment: android 4.0.3 lenovo tablet does not get edittext background

Comment: i don't see your background drawable having any background color. maybe it's using the default background of the phone's theme or something. check out @yuva's android below.

Comment: yeah yuva's answer is worked for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In drawable xml add below tag -

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
```

you will get edittext with white color inside

Comment: thanks yuva's it works for me...Feel ashamed for silly thing.